# VB.NET removing formatting from a formatted Phone number before inserting into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date, formatting

I have a string when a telephone number is inputted - there is a mask so it always looks like (123) 456-7890 - I'd like to take the formatting out before saving it to the DB. I have it set up to only 10 charachters as nvarchar(10) - I only need it to be numbers like this 1234567890.

Comment: what do you mean by a mask?  Are you using the MaskedEditControl?

Comment: @plutonix yes I have a masked control and i'm trying to basically insert only numbers into a nvarchar(10) field. My mask - "(___) ___-____"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to do it(basically replace every non number character with ""):

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions //You need to Import this Namespace

Dim phone as string = "(123) 456-7890 -"
Dim match as string = Regex.Replace(phone, "[^\d]", "")

Console.WriteLine(match)
```

*This outputs to: 1234567890*

Comment: maybe u can help me with this - I have a field in sql server set as Datetime - but from vb.net trying to insert Datetime.Now throws an error because of the PM

Comment: You can open another question and post the link here as a comment...you can also try to change your table field to datetime2 and see if the issue get fixed :)

Comment: Or use this: `Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Just one thing, you can probably edit your answe rif you want but you need to include this at the top of your form for REGEX to work.......... Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) then you could set the property [TextMaskFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.textmaskformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
masked1.Mask = "(999)999-9999" 
tb.Text = "(123)456-7890";
masked1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals
....
Console.WriteLine(masked1.Text)  ' => 1234567890
```

and when you get the Text property you get only the characters excluding the formatting characters

Notice that I have set the mask with 9 to allow only numbers. This of course depends on how telephone numbers are expected by your application.

Comment: this is great. Thanks!